# How to update existing object with partial data in restkit?

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I have get API which returns following data

```
{
    "id": "45832",
    "name": "test name",
    "parentId":"xyz",
    //other fields
}
```

I am able to save this data using restkit. I have another api to get changes which returns only updated fields. for example

```
{
    "id": "45832",
    "name": "test name2",
    //other updated fields
}
```

I want this data to update existing object in db. But in my case it sets `parentId` and other missing attributes to null. I have set identification attribute in entity mapping.

EDIT:

Here is the class for managed object with entity mapping.
    #import "ZEntity.h"
    #import "ZContent.h"
    #import "ZThumb.h"

```
@implementation ZEntity

@dynamic availableFrom;
@dynamic dueDate;
@dynamic entityId;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic perCompleted;
@dynamic state;
@dynamic type;
@dynamic thumb;
@dynamic contents;
@dynamic completedOn;
@dynamic totalScore;
@dynamic parent;
@dynamic settings;

+ (RKEntityMapping *)map{
    RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) inManagedObjectStore:[RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore]];
    mapping.persistentStore = [RKManagedObjectStore defaultStore].persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.firstObject;

    NSAssert(mapping.persistentStore != nil, @"Requires Persistent Store");

    mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"entityId"];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                              @"id" : @"entityId",
                                              @"type" : @"type",
                                              @"name" : @"name",
                                              @"dueDate" : @"dueDate",
                                              @"state" : @"state",
                                              @"availableFrom" :@"availableFrom",
                                              @"percCompletion" : @"perCompleted",
                                              @"completedOn" : @"completedOn",
                                              @"totalScore" : @"totalScore"
                                              }];
    [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"thumb" toKeyPath:@"thumb" withMapping:[ZThumb map]]];
    return mapping;
}

@end
```

Response descriptor

```
RKResponseDescriptor* entitiesD = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:[ZEntity map] 
    method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"objects" 
    statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

Json response

```
{
"total": 9,
"start": 1,
"count": 10,
"objects": [{
    "id": "636488166759829858",
    "type": "UPDATE",
    "name": "copy1",
    "canReattempt": false,
    "score": 0,
    "totalScore": 300,
    "thumb": {
        "id": "THUMB_QUPDATE4",
        "expiry": 1472545125,
        "url_180_120": "//s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/mtgame-cdn.mindtickle.com/allaboard4.0/thumb/Q-Update-Thumbnail_04.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJYDLQOOEIA6NZLPQ&Expires=1472545125&Signature=To8a5SN7CoCiWDmmtXLkyANKulw%3D"
    },
    "dueDate": 1440845008,
    "dueDateObj": {
        "dueOn": 1440845008,
        "dueDateExpiryAction": "NONE"
    },
    "state": "ACTIVE",
    "percCompletion": 0.0,
    "availableFrom": 1440585808,
    "completedOn": 0,
    "startTime": null,
    "expiryTime": null,
    "certificateCutOffScore": -1,
    "lastPublishTime": 1440585653,
    "completionCertificateEnabled": null
}]
}
```

In earlier calls I have set `parent` field for `Entity` class which is a relationship (I have verified this through sqlite browser too). In this json there is no parent returned. Once this call finished, parent is set to null. I have to keep existing parent value.

Comment: Please show the code you are using to update the object

Comment: Show your mapping and response descriptors. If there is nothing in the JSON then nothing will be changed in the data store, are you sure you aren't creating duplicates?

Comment: I have added code. Thanks